# Magento 2 table rate extension

Tags: magento2

There is a free extension that allows you to create multiple table rates simultaneously visible on the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some webshops I have used the MatrixRate in Magento 1 but there is also a Magento 2 version available

https://github.com/webshopapps/module-matrixrate/tree/master/src

Besides this if you want to manage Table Rates through the admin panel take a look at this Tablerate Manager

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-Tablerate-Manager

Comment: I will try the modules you have recommended me, thank you.